# Notation for transforming angle to an interval such as $(-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: notation, angle

Is there a standard or at least often used way of denoting the operation of transforming an angle into a specific interval?

For example, I would like to denote in the equation 
$$
\alpha = \beta - \gamma
$$
that after subtraction the resulting angle value is transformed to the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.

---

Edit: Right now I am thinking of using a notation like this, and just explaining what I mean by that in the text.
$$
\alpha = (\beta - \gamma)_{\in (-\pi, \pi]}
$$

But as far as I know this is not standard. (Would using a different type of brackets be more appropriate?)

Comment: How about $\alpha=\beta-\gamma\in(-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: Thanks, MPW. That's what I was thinking of too. I guess plain and simple is the best.

Comment: I would interpret $\alpha=\beta-\gamma\in(-\pi,\pi]$ as a statement that the difference $\beta-\gamma$ is already in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ and that no transformation was performed. That's literally what that formula says.

Comment: I agree that $\alpha=\beta-\gamma\in(-\pi,\pi]$ does not convey what you want to convey. "For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong." - H. L. Mencken

Answer (score 1):

You could say $\alpha \in (-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\alpha = \beta - \gamma +2n\pi,$
$n$ an integer.

(That is the transformation you had in mind, was it not?
Adding/subtracting some multiple of $2\pi$?)

Comment: Yes, that is the transformation. Writing like that certainly avoids ambiguity. Although I was hoping for something less verbose.

Comment: You can define a function using words like these once and then re-use the function as much as you want. Your notation $(\cdot)_{\in(-\pi,\pi]}$ could be defined that way. You could also juggle the "floor" function $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ with arithmetic so that you had a function expressed completely in math symbols with no words at all, but it would be a puzzle for the reader to decipher.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the *equivalent* angle in that range, then the map
$$f(\theta) = \pi - (\theta \operatorname{mod} 2\pi)$$
will produce the desired result. More generally,
$$b - (\theta \operatorname{mod} (b-a))\in (a,b]$$ for $a<b$ because
$$0\leq\theta\operatorname{mod} (b-a)<b-a$$

$$b-(b-a)<b-(\theta\operatorname{mod} (b-a))\leq b-0$$

$$a<b-(\theta\operatorname{mod} (b-a))\leq b$$